# Is there a way to open multiple memory dumps in OllyDbg?

Tags: debugging, memory, ollydbg

I would like to view multiple areas of memory at the same time in OllyDbg but there seems to be only a single "Dump" windows, which is activated by the "Show in Dump" command. Is there any way to get multiple such windows open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can have multiple Dump windows open.

Here is one way of going about it:

- Goto the 'Memory Map' window ( Window > Memory Map or Click the 'M' button).
- Once you're here, you can click on the memory segment of your choice.
- That will bring up a new Dump window.

You can do this any number of times to bring up more Dump windows.

Also, while in the Dump window(s), you can use Ctrl+G to bring the 'Enter address to follow' prompt. Enter the address that you want to jump to here.